# HTML Canvas animation wont run on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, canvas, html5-canvas

The canvas animation runs effectively on web browsers but when testing on mobile browsers with iPad and iPhone the animation never starts. It just simply displays the background image. There are no error messages given.

The animation is basically an image that moves from offscreen on the left hand side of the canvas and stops when it reaches 75% of the canvas width.

Heres the code

```
  <script>

  window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded, false);
        function eventWindowLoaded () {
        start();
    }

    function canvasSupport () {
        return Modernizr.canvas;
    }  

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");    
    var cw=canvas.width;
    var ch=canvas.height;

    var image1 = new Image();
    image1.onload = function() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 400);
        ctx.drawImage(image1, 0, 0);
    }
    image1.src="images/oven.jpg";   
    ctx.fillStyle = image1;

    var currentX=cw;
    var continueAnimating=true;
    var nextMoveTime,maxMoves;
    var expX = 50;
    var expY = 200;


    var image2 = new Image();
    image2.onload=start;
    image2.src="images/pies.png"; 

    var image = new Image();
    image.onload=start;
    image.src="images/pies.png"; 



    function start(){

      maxMoves=(cw+image.width)*0.5;

      nextMoveTime=performance.now();

      requestAnimationFrame(animate);




    function animate(currentTime){

      if(continueAnimating){ requestAnimationFrame(animate); }

      if(currentTime<nextMoveTime){return;}

      nextMoveTime=currentTime; // + delay;


      ctx.drawImage(image,currentX,193);

      if(--currentX<-image.width){ currentX=cw; }

      if(--maxMoves<0){continueAnimating=false;}
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: performance.now is not supported on ipad/iphone.  See here : http://caniuse.com/#search=navigation

Comment: @GameAlchemist Thanks for letting me know, is there any alternatives that you are aware of that would be suitable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue comes from your use of performance.now, which is not always implemented, especially on mobile devices where the power drain of a precise timer is too high.
Just use the time provided with the requestAnimationFrame : on accurate browsers/devices, it will use the sub-millisecond accuracy, otherwise it will have only millisecond accuracy.
(accurate = Chrome desktop for sure,... others ???)

I'll let you see below how i use the time of rAF to build the current 'dt' = elapsed time since last frame, and 'applicationTime' = time elapsed in the application (*not* counting when you tabbed out the app).

A secondary benefit of this method is that you can change easily the application speed to have 'bullet-time' or speed up (or even rewind if speed is <0).

fiddle is here :

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/KVDsc/

```
// current application time, in milliseconds.
var applicationTime = 0;    
// scale applied to time. 
// 1 means no scale, <1 is slower, >1 faster.
var timeSpeed = 1;

// after launchAnimation is called, 
//  draw/handleInput/update will get called on each rAF
function launchAnimation() {
    requestAnimationFrame(_launchAnimation);
}

// ------------- Private methods ----------------

function _launchAnimation(now) {
    _lastTime = now;
    applicationTime = 0
    requestAnimationFrame(_animate);
}

// ----------------------------------------------
// Animation.
//   Use launchAnimate() to start the animation.
//     draw, handleInput, update will be called every frame.
// ----------------------------------------------
function _animate(now) {
    requestAnimationFrame(_animate);
    // _______________________
    var dt = now - _lastTime;
    if (dt < 12) return; // 60 HZ max
    if (dt > 200) dt = 16; // consider 1 frame elapse on tab-out 
    _lastTime = now;
    dt *= timeSpeed;
    applicationTime += dt;
    // _______________________
    handleInput(); // ...
    // update everything with this frame time step.
    update(dt);
    // draw everything    
    draw();
}
var _lastTime = 0;
```

(( Notice that to handle most gracefully the tab-out, you have to handle the blur event, cancel the rAF, then set-it again on focus. ))

Comment: any idea why changing the background color of canvas in the "middle" of an animation would cause canvas to glitch out and seemingly stop drawing or not remove a frame? i would probably have to show you a video for this to make sense (although i have already fixed it by not changing the background color of canvas mid-animation and dont have the time to make a video and post a new question)

Answer (score 0):

```
var now =
    ( typeof performance === 'object' && 'now' in performance )
    ? function() { return performance.now(); }
    : function() { return ( new Date ).getTime(); };
```

Comment: var now = ( performance && performance.now ) ? performance.now.bind(performance) : Date.now ;   is way better.